# Can a windows phone app read Message from USSD request?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-7.1

Can a windows phone app read the message from USSD request? For example, my app dial *126# USSD code to request balance check, then it will pop out a message with balance. Here, I would like to read/copy this message with balance into my app. Is it possible to do so?

Best regards

Chong Han

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry You don't have access to Messages in Windows phone. There always be the security Constraint for these kind of stuffs.

But you can use some web services to send and receive the messages.

Thanks

Comment: Can I have some info for web services to send/receive message? If use for balance checking, is it can be done by web services?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, this is not possible.